# Automatically append to an Access 2007 table when leaving a textbox in VB.NET

Tags: data-binding, ado.net, vb.net-2010

I am a beginner at VB.NET but I have some Access experience.  I know I will have many needs for this ability so let me just ask for code pertaining to 2 TextBoxes on a VB.NET 2010 form.  Tab oder is TextBox1 is 0 and TextBox2 is 1.  Type in text into TextBox1 and press TAB, Enter, or Mouse click to TextBox2 and whatever you typed into TextBox1 will be transfered to an Access 2007 table/record.  I have read that ADO is better than data binding.  If so, then I'd like to see both ways.  Thank you very much for your valuable time.  I appreaciate it.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Write an handler for the **Leave** event on textbox1. This code will be executed when textbox1 will lose its focus.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Me.Text = "Left the control"
    'here you'll insert the code that will append data to your Access table
End Sub
```